# What are possible experimental (optical/microscopic/spectroscopic) observables for identifying and differentiating superconductivity?

Tags: optics, condensed-matter, superconductivity, spectroscopy, observables

In a system one is analysing for superconductivity signatures, what are possible experimental (optical/microscopic/spectroscopic) observables for identifying and differentiating superconductivity?